# How to fix flutter web TextFormField not accepting nor responding to input?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I created this code snippet to create a login web form in flutter web application, in which I used TextFormField, it is displayed well but when I try to input any characters in this field, it doesn't respond and no input is taken, how can this be solved please?

```
class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  LoginFormState createState() {
    return LoginFormState();
  }
}

class LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Row(children: <Widget>[
            // Email input field
            Container(
              width: 120.0,
              child: Text(
                "Email: *",
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontFamily: 'Merriweather',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 40.0,
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4.0,
              child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                cursorColor: Colors.black,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'e@x.y',
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.black87,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return "Please enter your email!";
                  }
                  return "yayyy";
                },
              ),
            ),
          ])
        ]));
  }
}
```

Expected: user can enter input in the textFormfield
Error: User can't enter any input and the scroll keep blinking only

Update: This is the code that incubates the form itself, hope it helps.

```
import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';
/*import 'package:login_page/widgets/agree.dart';
import 'package:login_page/widgets/gender.dart';
**/
import 'package:dart_flutter_web_preview/widgets/login_form.dart';
import 'home.dart';

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white, // ignore: undefined_operator
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 60.0, bottom: 60.0, left: 120.0, right: 120.0),
          child: Card(
            // ignore: argument_type_not_assignable
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: Container(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.3,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    color: Color(0xFFCFE8E4),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 85.0, right: 50.0, left: 50.0),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(height: 60),
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
                              //color: Colors.red,
                              child: Text(
                                'Go Ahead and Login',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 30.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontFamily: 'Merriweather',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5),
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                              //color: Colors.red,
                              child: Text(
                                'It should only take a couple of seconds to login to your account',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  fontFamily: 'Merriweather',
                                  //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 30.0,
                            ),
                            RaisedButton(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                  return Home();
                                }));
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'Home',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontFamily: 'Merriweather',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 140.0, right: 30.0, left: 30.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.3,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Login",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                            fontSize: 35.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Merriweather',
                          ),
                          //textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 30.0,
                        ),
                        new LoginForm(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  } //Widget
} //
```

Comment: Did you try to wrap your form in Scaffold ?

Comment: I tried yes but nothing changed. It may be due to versions issues. Some people on Egyptian geeks mentioned this.

Comment: There is so much enhancment in latest version, I wrape it with scaffold and tested your code it works fine.

Comment: I think I have to upgrade my version then. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried as mentioned by other helpful contributors, to upgrade my flutter version and it worked. So, the solution for this lies in upgrading the version as many new updates were added.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and the only problem i had is that on the snippet you don't have a scaffold, but since i put a scaffold everything works as expected.

What is probably happening is that your widget is rebuilding every time you are typing something and you are losing the data. Can you please give the whole code?

Comment: Thank you for your response and Im Sorry for being late to reply. Actually I am having a problem with my github account so, I will update the question body with the code that incubates the form itself

Comment: I don't know if a copied and pasted the wrong pieces, but is still working fine here

Comment: with your added code snippet: the scaffold? Please let me know any way to share the code with you.

Comment: and you would you please let me know how it differs, a container from scaffold as I already wrapped the form in a container?